# An exception has been thrown during the rendering?

Tags: symfony, twig, rendering

i want to get the "PublisherId" from my twig file.

it returns me an error ----**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "myBundle_publisher" as such route does not exist.")**

I read the twig documentation and there it also write like how i write it.

Do anyone knows how i can solve this problem . Really stack here, can someone solve this problem, thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routes need to be imported to be active as any other routing resources (note the annotation type):

```
# import routes from a controller class
post:
    resource: "@SensioBlogBundle/Controller/PostController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

More information about [@Route](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)